# How do I fix file cache issue on Google Chrome in Android (5.1)?

Tags: android, google-chrome, caching

As part of a study, I use a website (.NET) to administer an experiment via a tablet and 4G WiFi modem. The experiment involves downloading a total of 70MB of images from the website as it goes from page to page, with each page downloading around 5MB of images each.

I have written an application cache manifest file "dvams.appcache" in which I list all of the image files and other resources which I wish to have cached locally on my tablet. In the aspx page using the image files, I have included the manifest attribute (manifest="dvams.appcache") in the HTML element, as directed.

However, when I run my experiments out in the field, Chrome (version 43) does not seem to take any notice of the manifest file, and the files do not persist locally on my tablet for more than a short period of time, after which Chrome behaves as if they have been removed from the cache.

In every experimental run I do, the browser continues to retrieve a lot of files it has already downloaded from the website. The speed of my 4G connection varies markedly, and downloading these files time and time again is excruciatingly slow, with pages taking as long as 2 or 3 minutes to download the required image files.

My theory is that the file cache size needs to be increased to accommodate the 70MB of files I wish to be cached, or that an "offline mode" setting that used to exist in earlier versions of chrome (but did appear to work) needs to be set somewhere. I have seen how a cache size parameter "--disk-cache-size=104857600" can be added as a parameter to the chrome executable file when called from Windows, but cannot figure out how to accomplish this on Android 5.1.

Why are these cached files being deleted? How can I force Chrome/Android to ALWAYS go to the cache for images it has already downloaded, and make these offline files persist PERMANENTLY unless I manually tell Chrome to clear them?